# Share context between unit test and web api in a C# project

Tags: c#, dbcontext

How can I share the context that the test project created while running with the context of the web api?  If the web api creates its context from environment variable, that will be different to that the unit test project creates. (In addition, I concat a guid to the database name, so as each test class have different database name that can run asynchron.)

Thank you.

This is how web api creates context in Program.cs

```
var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

And this is how test project creates:

```
public TestBase()
    {
        var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
        connectionString = connectionString.Replace("dbName", "dbName" + Guid.NewGuid());

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>()
           .UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options;
        context = new Context(options);
        context.Database.Migrate();
    }
```

Comment: U can mock a db context

Comment: What is the test framework? xunit? MsTest? NUnit?

Comment: What is the web Framework? ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I use MSTest and ASP.NET CORE WEB.API 6.0. May I ask you why the type of the test framework is important? The context creation process is independent of the test framework.

Comment: Agrre, test framework isn't necessary information.

Comment: Do you use the minimal API or the classic controller MVC?

Comment: The classic one.

Comment: In the test, you can set a environnement variable with [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable)

Comment: But if I modify the environment variable I cannot run multiple test classes simultanously with different test db names (guid this case)

Comment: A other solution is to override the DbContext. See my answer to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in the past is having it like:

```
internal ApplicationDbContext dbContext;

public BaseCoreTest()
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

    var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>().UseSqlServer(builder.Build()["ConnectionStrings:Default"]).Options;

    dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);
}
```

Comment: I had the same solution, but with environment variables. In case the env variables are different in test and SUT project, both the databases are cerated separeted (And the test db is deleted because of the dispose(). In case they are the same, the test can reach the SUT data, but I don't think it is a good solution because the dbContext is not shared.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [Integration tests in ASP.NET Core > Inject mock services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#inject-mock-services-1)

> Services can be overridden in a test with a call to [ConfigureTestServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.webhostbuilderextensions.configuretestservices?view=aspnetcore-6.0) on the host builder. To inject mock services, the SUT must have a Startup class with a Startup.ConfigureServices method.

You can use `ConfigureTestServices` to override the context service like :

```cs
public TestBase()
{
    var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
    connectionString = connectionString.Replace("dbName", "dbName" + Guid.NewGuid());

    var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<Context>>();
            services.AddDbContext<Context>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        });
    });
    Application = application;
    using var scope = application.Services.CreateScope();
    using var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<Context>();
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

Comment: The db name here in the connectionstring is a guid, but when debugging context creation in Program.cs the db name is the normal name. And how can I get the context here, since I need it in test.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how get the context.

Comment: the db is created with the connectionstring given in Program.cs, not the guid one. And the context is disposed later when I need it. (I cannot pass it to the   internal Context context { get; set; })

Comment: My bad, I try to simplify the example and miss something. I updated my answer, see the line `services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<Context>>();`